# "Had it been" other usages

Tags: expressions

Recently, I came across a very interesting expression (I shall consider it as an expression) - *Had it been.*

**Ex:** Two boys were caught robbing

- Had it been two girls, no one would have paid attention.

Can such an expression be used with other verbs such as:

**Ex:** Two boys were caught robbing

- Had it robbed a bank, no one would have cared.

Answer (score 1):

This is called inversion.  The verb "had" is in the subjunctive mood, specifically the past perfect subjunctive conjugation "had been".  The subjunctive mood allows, in modern times, for its auxiliary verbs to be inverted:

> **Were** I a very rich man, I would buy a yacht and sail the *ocean blue*. (**"Were I"** is the inverted past subjunctive of **"If I
>   were"**; *"ocean blue"* is a form of inversion as well: "blue ocean".)
>
> **Should** he be found guilty, he may receive the death penalty. (**"Should"** is inverted to replace the present subjunctive **"If he
>   be"** or **"If he should be"**.)
>
> No man, **be** he patrician or plebeian, is above the law. (**"be"**
>   is inverted to replace the present subjunctive **"Whether / if he be"**; even though "be" may not be acting as an auxiliary in this specific instance, "be" can always be inverted because of its auxiliary tendency.)

There are also fossilized forms of the inverted subjunctive in idioms.  Because they are idioms and are fossilized forms of how it was once said in bygone times, these verbs don't have to be auxiliary verbs to be inverted:

> **Know** *all men* by these presents... (*"all men"* is the subject "they"; the statement is saying, "let all men know".)
>
> **Suffice** it to say... (This means, "Let it be sufficient to say".)
>
> **Come** January / tomorrow / [whenever]... (This means, "Whenever January / tomorrow (may) come".)

Of course, there are inverted auxiliary subjunctives that are fossilized in idioms as well:

> **Be** it remembered... (This means, "let it be remembered".)
>
> **Be** that as it may... (This means, "If that be as it may be".)
>
> **Be** it ever so humble... (This means, "Even though it (may) be very humble".)

In essence, inversion is common in the subjunctive form.  In your example,

> **Had** they robbed a bank, no one would have cared.

the auxiliary verb "had" is in the past perfect subjunctive form ("had been"), so you can always invert "had" here if you want:

> **Had** I the time, I would help you out. (past subjunctive "had"; although had is not acting as an auxiliary verb in this specific instance, "had" can always be inverted because of its auxiliary tendency.)
>
> **Had** I seen the bank robbery, I would have called the police. (past perfect subjunctive "had seen")
>
> **Had** it been two girls, no one would have paid attention. (past perfect subjunctive "had been")

Inversion is mandatory in "neither...nor" constructions:

> I am *neither* stupid, *nor* **am** I a fool.

Inversion can sometimes be used for style in the middle of a clause:

> The more he steals, the more likely **is** he to be caught.

However, such a construction is not mandatory:

> The more he steals, the more likely he **is** to be caught.

Inversion is a confusing aspect of English because English is a syncretic language; therefore, it's hard to differentiate whether it's merely a subject-verb inversion or a verb-direct-object structure, especially when a pronoun is not used ("know all men" becomes "know they").

I hope this might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck!

**P.S.** "Did" is not one of the auxiliaries that can be inverted to form the subjunctive in Modern English; therefore, one cannot say:

> "**Did I** it, I would be caught." (incorrect English in *Modern
>   English*)

Comment: Interesting. So I can invert any verb position in order to form the subjunctive:

**If I did it, I would be caught** becomes **Did I it, I would be caught**
 
and 

**If I had done it, I would have been caught** becomes **Had I done it, I would have been caught**

correct?

Comment: In modern English, you can only invert certain auxiliary verbs such as "to be", "to have", and "should": "**Had I done** it, I would have been caught."; "**Were I** a better student, I could graduate in four years."; "**Should I fail** this exam, I shall not pass this class."; however, "did" is not one you can invert in the subjunctive. It's the exception to the rule of auxiliaries.

Comment: You can do it in the present subjunctive though for the same verbs as seen in "should", but it can be very archaic-sounding: "**Be he** tall or not, he can still play basketball."; "**Have he** the time, he will help you." Usually, if  we wanted to preserve the subjunctive here, we'd say, "**Should he be** tall or not" or "**Should he have** the time."

Comment: Interesting, Nick. I can only use this inversion when the inverted verb has auxiliary functions (even if it is not acting as an auxiliary in that sentence) - **Were I a boy, I would wear different things** - I can invert it because **to be** is also an auxiliary verb even though it is not acting as one there, correct?

**Had I a car, I would ride throughout the country** - I can invert it here because the verb **have** also has an auxiliary function (even though it is not acting as one here), correct?

Comment: Basically, the only verbs you can invert in the subjunctive mood are "to be", "to have", and "should": "Were I a boy..."; "Had I a car..."; "Should that be the case...."  "be" and "have" should only be inverted in the past subj.; in the present subj., they can be very archaic-sounding, but they aren't incorrect per se: "Be he tall or small, he can try out for basketball." "Have I the time, I shall help you." These present subjunctive inverted uses are very archaic, but not incorrect. You may see them in old literature, but you won't hear them said often except maybe with "be" once a year.

Comment: For instance, I've said and written before something like, "No man, **be he** patrician or plebeian, is above the law." This is the inverted present subjunctive using "be" and it's very formal.

Comment: Any other inversions using the subjunctive besides the verb "be" are normally idiomatic expressions from long ago: "Suffice it to say"; Know all men by these presents". Many of the ones using "be" in inversion are also fossilized idiomatic expressions: "Be that as it may"; "Be it ever so humble"; "albeit" = "although it be"; "Be it remembered / known".

Comment: If you want to invert the present subjunctive using any other verb like "know" or "lose", you should use "should": "Should he know the answer..."; "Should he lose the game...." The past subjunctive cannot be inverted with any other verb, however, except "were" and "had".

Answer (score 0):

The [**irrealis mood**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood) can be used with other verbs, but you would not use the dummy subject *it* as you've done in your example.

> Had ***they*** robbed a bank, no one would have cared.

Here *they* is a pronoun referring to the two boys you mention.

Comment: The irrealis mood is what some modern grammarians call it now, but if we should look at English diachronically, there is no irrealis mood; it's the subjunctive mood. For instance, I could call an apple a **fruit** today, but maybe 1,000 years from now, humans will categorize it as *flotchka* (made-up word) because they have found that apples don't fit into the category of fruit in their time anymore. Despite future humans calling an apple *flotchka* instead of *fruit*, the apple is still a *fruit* with just a different name.

Comment: Because modern grammarians have been trying to roust the subjunctive from English for so long, some of them have renamed the past subjunctive as "irrealis" even though, diachronically, it has always been the subjunctive; but just because we change the name of something doesn't mean that that something has actually changed; only its name has changed. I could call "garbage" "flowers" and ask people, "Do you like the flowers around my house?" Even though I call my garbage "flowers", that doesn't change the fact that it is still "garbage".

Comment: I would have called it subjunctive had I not been already well peppered by people who insist that the subjunctive is dead and it serves no purpose to talk about it. *Irrealis* is the trendy umbrella term, of course, and I gave in to it. I expect it's a case of damned if you do, damned if you don't. The point I'm making in the answer still stands, however.

Comment: I know. I hate trendy, little umbrella terms; don't you? Your answer is fine. I don't give in to those people who want to call it the irrealis mood. I like to balk by going against the grain.